# Select an Image button using Selenium inside anchor tag

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

How can i select an Image Button which look's like the below code Using Selenium in C#.I have Used Xpath to Find the Element.

```
<a onclick="resetValues();UploadFile();" href="#">
   <img alt="Upload Selected" src="images/buttons/button_template.gif">
</a>
```

Here's the Xpath Which  i have tried.
`Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//img[@alt='Upload Selected']/"))).Click()`

Comment: Remove the `"/"` at the end of your xpath `"//img[@alt='Upload Selected']/"` and change it to `//img[@alt='Upload Selected']`. It might be the reason why your code might be failing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using any of the Xpath from below. It should work for you

```
(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='resetValues();UploadFile();']//img"))
```

or

```
(By.xpath("//img[@src ='images/buttons/button_template.gif']"))
```

or

```
(By.xpath("//img[@src ='images/buttons/button_template.gif' and @alt='Upload Selected']"))
```

Comment: Any reason why `//img[@alt='Upload Selected']` should not work and you have to change the expression to something completely different?

Comment: off-course if its the only attribute with value 'Upload Selected' then it will work too. The reason i have not mentioned is because you used the same method in your answer and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Selenium, only with XPath.)

XPath expressions that end with `/` are not valid. Simply remove the `/` at the end:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//img[@alt='Upload Selected']"))).Click()
```

Also, I'm not sure why `string.Format()` is in there, but then again, I'm not familiar with Selenium.